# How to make foreign key as NULLABLE in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
    CREATE TABLE [M].[SocialInfo]
    (
        [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newid(), 
[MemberId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  DEFAULT newid(),
    [GroupId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  DEFAULT newid(),
        [NewsURL] VARCHAR(200) NULL,     
        CONSTRAINT [FK_SocialInfo_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([MemberId]) REFERENCES [M].[Member]([Id]), 
        CONSTRAINT [FK_SocialInfo_Group] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [M].[Group]([Id]) 
    )
```

> How can I make both FK nullable?
>
> I'm unable to get the syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Comment: Different question now altogether... you can't do default newid() on a fk column. The newid that has not been created yet will need to exist in the Member/Group table before you're allowed to insert it into SocialInfo table. Look into using triggers for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Do not use `NEWID()` as it will fragment your indexes by inserting seemingly random GUID strings. You are much better off using `NEWSEQUENTIALID` or even better by using an INT or BIG into as your ID values.

Comment: It's probably better to remove default newid() and just wrap all this in a store procedure so that it insert with default newid() in Member/Group table then use that to insert into SocialInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just left out the column creation piece.

```
CREATE TABLE [M].[SocialInfo]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newid(), 
    [NewsURL] VARCHAR(200) NULL,     
    MemberId INT NULL,
    GroupId INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SocialInfo_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([MemberId]) REFERENCES [M].[Member]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SocialInfo_Group] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [M].[Group]([Id]) 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A default value for a foreign key makes no sense - use NULL instead

```
CREATE TABLE [M].[SocialInfo]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newid(), 
    [MemberId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NULL,
    [GroupId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  NULL,
    [NewsURL] VARCHAR(200) NULL,     
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SocialInfo_Member] FOREIGN KEY ([MemberId]) REFERENCES [M].[Member]([Id]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_SocialInfo_Group] FOREIGN KEY ([GroupId]) REFERENCES [M].[Group]([Id]) 
)
```

Comment: I disagree.  I prefer the approach of a default value pointing to a record in the parent table that means something like Not Applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think  you need to put NULL keyword as it is shown in below link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/325c11b9-e5c4-4db7-94e6-f82b44412b9b/is-it-possible-to-allow-null-values-in-foreign-key?forum=transactsql

Also this sqlfiddle may be helpful

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39a0b/10