# insert IdentityUser with default values and custom properties fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm building on a couple of posts here:

- [How to extend available properties of User.Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335353/how-to-extend-available-properties-of-user-identity)
- [How to extend IdentityUser with custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532987/how-to-extend-identityuser-with-custom-property/40579369)

So I've extended my IdentityUser with custom properties; that's all working well. These custom properties are designated in SQL Server as having default values, i.e. if I insert a new user, the default values for these custom props should just pop in, right?

No - they fail with NULL value (since they are designated with NOT NULL), and if I open them up to be not NOT NULL, they fail here (at the AddClaim line),

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
{
    // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
    var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    // Add custom user claims here
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("companyId", this.companyId.ToString()));

    return userIdentity;
}
```

because even though the companyId default val is set in mssql = "newcompanyid", it never sets from NULL and so comes back as NULL.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "the default vals for these custom props should just pop in right" - Assuming this is all backed by an Entity Framework DbContext, then no. You have to change the mapped property to one of the StoreGeneratedPattern values - I usually change it to Identity.

Comment: Shot in the dark here but just to confirm:         // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("companyId", this.groupId.ToString()));... Is this meant to be group id or company id?

Comment: @Mitchell - yes except i made a type - updated now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to tieson
i was able to fix this using this technique:

http://www.vannevel.net/2015/04/03/how-to-configure-a-custom-identityuser-for-entity-framework/

with a basis in the following:

- [SQL column default value with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038524/sql-column-default-value-with-entity-framework)
- https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute

so in the end my code looked like:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int companyId { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("companyId", this.companyId.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

hope this helps someone else