# EF Core insert only some columns from entity class

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

EF Core always include ALL the columns of the class in the `INSERT` statement. How can I modify the script so that the `INSERT` statement will only include values for which I have provided a value?

Let's say I have a User class with 3 properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }   // this one is linked to a auto increment ID column
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Amount { get; set; }   // linked to a column that cannot be null and has a default value configured in SQL Server
```

So what I am doing to insert a new record into the User table is:

```
User newUser = new User();
newUser.Name = "John";
await _dbc.AddAsync(newUser);
await _dbc.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The `INSERT` statement will include `Name = "JOHN"`, BUT will also include `Amount = null`, so the query will fail because null is not accepted for Amount. I want to remove the `Amount` column from the generated `INSERT` statement to simply send

```
INSERT INTO User (NAME) 
VALUES ('John')
```

and I want to let the SQL Server insert the default configured value into the `Amount` column.

It is a simple example, my real situation have many columns for which I have default value for insertion, and I do not want the `INSERT` statement that is generated to include ALL the columns from the `User` class, only those for which I provide a value.

Comment: This sounds like your data models are not configured properly. Can you include the configuration for the User model?

Comment: you just said that DB does not accept null. Hence you need to set your model to the default value.  See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038524/sql-column-default-value-with-entity-framework

Comment: I am using this tool to generate my models: efg.loresoft.com/quickStart so if I modify my models, as soon as I will update them by running "efg generate" with this tool, it will remove any changes made... and I haven't found a way to setup this tool to add required default values from sql server.

Comment: so there is no simple way to simply build INSERT statements FIELD BY FIELD, still using the model to refer to them, but not including all properties of the class (other than writing your own SQL query) ?

Comment: If you write to someone you must include @userName otherwise we dont get notified about your comment

Comment: I think, you need this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3642740/1704458

Answer (score 0):

For model properties which are not nullable and have a database default, you will want to either annotate or configure the property to make EF aware of the database default.

This article demonstrates both: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonadd-method

Using the fluent configuration, you'll want to add `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`. For example:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    public partial class UserConfiguation : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
        {
            // ... other field configurations
 
            builder
                .Property(m => m.Amount)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();


            OnConfigurePartial(builder);
        }

        partial void OnConfigurePartial(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder);
    }
}
```

As a data annotation, you'll use DatabaseGeneratedAttribute:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace YourNamespaceHere
{
    [Table(nameof(User))]
    public class User
    {
        // ... other properties

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using this tool to generate my models: https://efg.loresoft.com/quickStart/ I do agree that .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() is a solution, but as soon as I will update my models by running "efg generate" with this tool, it will remove it... and I haven't found a way to setup this tool to auto generate .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() for columns having default value in sql server...

Comment: @Phil Can't really help you there. Probably need to either not rely on that tool beyond the initial setup or find a better tool. For example, https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools

Comment: thanks for trying to help! I just installed EFCorePowerTools and generated my Models from it. Same behavior than the other tool, it will not add  ValueGeneratedOnAdd for columns not allowing null and having default values configured in SQL Server... So I still get CANNOT INSERT NULL INTO X col... And if I add ValueGeneratedOnAdd on some columns manually, then re-run the tool, it will remove them just like the other tool.

Comment: Unless your models are constantly changing, I think you're going to have to decide which is more important. I generally only use things like the Power Tools to generate an initial set of models and configuration values, then rely on manual updates to change things later. At the end of the day, your only options are to a) find a tool that does what you want (not going to be something free, I suspect), b) update your tables to have nullable columns, or c) no rely on the tooling to do all the heavy lifting (in the end, your best bet).

Comment: so there is no simple way to simply build INSERT statements, FIELD BY FIELD, still using the model to refer to them, but not including all properties of the class (other than writing your own SQL query) right ?

Comment: Not with Entity Framework, no. EF builds it's queries based on a combination of configuration and convention. Without explicit configuration values, it falls back to "all non-nullable fields must be included in an insert". Granted, EF gives you access to the underlying ADO.NET components, so you can write and execute a custom insert query if you wanted to. That's fine if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

If creating the object doesn't require specifying the amount at that moment, why not make it nullable?

It seems like a design issue. Won't the amount be necessary at another time? If the answer is no, why not remove it from the table?

Otherwise, making it nullable seems like a good option, and later you can edit the record by inserting the amount.

```
public int Id { get; set; } 
public string Name { get; set; }
//By doing this, when creating the migration, the database understands that this property can accept null values.
public int? Amount { get; set; }
```