# MySql Update and Set null to field with foreign key to other table

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables like this:

```
Notes
ID | NAME | CATEGORY
1  | test | 1
2  | test2| 2

Notes Category
ID | NAME | COUNT
1  | tCat | 1
2  | tCat2| 1
```

And I have foreign key `CATEGORY <-> Notes Category.ID`

I try update first record in Notes and set the null as CATEGORY because I want to have notes without category and I get errror:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Do you have a "NOT NULL" constraint on your Notes CATEGORY column?  If so, that might be the reason.

Comment: no CATEGORY column have only unsigned

Comment: Are [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null) what you are looking for?

Comment: Well, if I had to guess, it would be that you're trying to update the Notes table with a CATEGORY value that does not correspond to any ID in the Notes Category table.

Comment: yes but if i try write query in phpmyadmin and use SET CATEGORY = NULL it's works

Comment: Works without any warning in phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `Notes` DROP FOREIGN KEY Notes_ibfk_1;
UPDATE `Notes` SET CATEGORY = NULL WHERE ID = 1;
ALTER TABLE `Notes` ADD FOREIGN KEY -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifically declaring CATEGORY as INT NULL in the NOTES table