# Make Foreign Key (string field) nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My model is like this

```
 public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public string AppointmentCode { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserId ")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public int PriceId { get; set; }
}
```

I expect `ApplicationUserId` to be nullable Foreign Key , But it is not created like that on table

```
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Appointment_dbo.IdentityUser_ApplicationUserId] FOREIGN KEY ([ApplicationUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[IdentityUser] ([Id]),
```

Can anyone point out correct approach to achieve this?

> Note: I am using Entity framework code first approach

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Comment: What version of EF is this? BTW you can put your own logic for schema generation stuff by using Up method from DbMigration class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By your model, I guess you are trying to create an one-to-many relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `Appointment` (one user could have more than one `Appointment`). If that is the case, you could configure that relationship in the `OnModelCreating` method on your context this way:

```
modelbuilder.Entity<Appoiment>().HasOptional(a=>a.ApplicationUser)
                                .WithMany(au=>au.Appointments)
                                .HasForeignKey(a=>ApplicationUserId);
```

Check this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) and go to the section "*Nullable foreign key for one-to-many relationship.*"

Comment: This throws a compile time error
Error 1 The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>' App\Models\Appointment.cs 104 24 DiagnosisApp

Comment: it's true, string is a reference type, so you don't need to declare that property as nullable, try just with the configuration.

Comment: `HasOptional` doesn't exist on `EntityTypeBuilder`... ef core 5.0.12

Answer (score 5):

For EF core, you can write below codes in OnModelCreating :

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Appoiment>().HasOne(a => a.ApplicationUser)
                .WithMany(au => au.Appointments)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.ApplicationUserId)
                .IsRequired(false);

    }
```