# Why can't I -- or how do I -- insert NULL values into my MySQL database using the WordPress API

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, database-design

I've been working on this for hours and can't figure out how to insert/update `NULL` values for columns. For example, I have a block of code

```
    case 'add':
    {
        $message = $wpdb->insert('projs', array('compname' => $compname, 'projname' => $projname, 'imageurl' => $imageurl, 'sumsmall' => $sumsmall, 'sumfull' => $sumfull, 'results' => $results, 'caseid' => $caseid, 'hide' => $hide)) 
                    ? 'Successfully added project to the database.'
                    : 'Error occurred when trying to add project to database: ' . $wpdb->last_error;
        break;
    }
```

and whenever it is executed with `$caseid` being equal to `null` (in PHP land) the query fails with `wpdb->last_error` being

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('my_table_name', 'projs', CONSTRAINT 'projs_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY
>   ('caseid') REFERENCES 'cases' ('id') ON DELETE SET NULL

For reference, the tables projs and cases are created during installation with

```
// Add table to hold the project portfolio
if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'projs'") != 'projs')
{
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE projs (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, compname VARCHAR (200), projname VARCHAR (200), imageurl VARCHAR(300), sumsmall VARCHAR (250), sumfull VARCHAR (5000), results VARCHAR (5000), postdate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, caseid MEDIUM INT, FOREIGN KEY (caseid) REFERENCES cases(id) ON DELETE SET NULL) $charset_collate");
}
// Add table to hold the case studies
if ($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'cases'") != 'cases')
{
    $wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE cases (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, compname VARCHAR (200), casename VARCHAR (200), imageurl VARCHAR(300), summary VARCHAR (5000), results VARCHAR (5000), postdate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) $charset_collate");
}
```

and I don't see how inserting a `NULL` value for `caseid` in `projs` violates anything.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` function expects to be called on a `TIMESTAMP` datatype, not `DATETIME`.

Note the `ON DELETE SET NULL` will cause issues if the table is InnoDB

```
CREATE TABLE projs (
id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
compname VARCHAR (200), 
projname VARCHAR (200), 
imageurl VARCHAR(300), 
sumsmall VARCHAR (250), 
sumfull VARCHAR (5000), 
results VARCHAR (5000), 
postdate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
caseid MEDIUMINT, 
FOREIGN KEY (caseid) REFERENCES cases(id) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: So is your comment referring to what you believe is the source of my problem, or is it a separate problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it isn't letting you insert a `NULL` value in general. It's that it is specifically not letting you insert a `NULL` value into `caseid`.

Because of the foreign key constraint linking `caseid` to the `id` column in `cases`, it is expecting a value equal to one of those `id`s.

You should have no trouble inserting `NULL` values into any of the other columns (except `id`, of course.)

Comment: So foreign keys can't be nullable? What if I want a column in a table to be possibly, but not necessarily, associated with a column in another table? For my application, some rows of `projs` are associated with rows of `cases`, but don't have to necessarily be.

Comment: I believe that you could allow nulls in your foreign key by explicitly defining that column as nullable in your create. (i.e. `caseid MEDIUM INT NULL`)

Comment: Here's a good Q&A about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null