# Can't create table 'mydb.contact' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

Please, this is my sql script

```
#-- creation de la table user
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user(
  iduser int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nom VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  prenom VARCHAR(50) ,
  adressemail VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  motdepasse VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY(iduser)
);


#-- creation de la table user
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contact(
  idcontact INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nom VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  prenom VARCHAR(45),
  adressemail VARCHAR(200) UNIQUE,
  user_iduser INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_contact PRIMARY KEY(idcontact),
  CONSTRAINT fk_contact_userIduser_user FOREIGN KEY (user_iduser) REFERENCES user(iduser) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

When i executing it on my maria db database, I get this error:

`Can't create table 'mydb.contact' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your foreign key constraint you have set the action on delete to `set null`, but the column `user_iduser` does not allow null values as it is specified as `not null` which makes the constraint invalid. Either change the column to allow null values or change the delete action in the constraint.

The online MySQL manual even has [a warning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) about this:

> If you specify a SET NULL action, *make sure that you have not declared
>   the columns in the child table as NOT NULL*.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `ON DELETE SET NULL` is restricting you to create table as your column `user_iduser` cannot be NULL as you written

```
 user_iduser INT NOT NULL
```

Comment: It's not the primary key that's being set to null, it's the foreign key in the referencing table and the issue is that it's set to not null.

Comment: Yes. I also mean the same thing as it is primary key in its own table.

Comment: iduser is a primary key in user table and user_iduser is a foreign key which is referencing to iduser. So, it cannot be null

Comment: Yes user_iduser is not PK in contact. But it is referencing to a primary key which is iduser. So it cannot be null

Comment: Sure it can be null. The constraint is only enforced for non-null data. See this for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Comment: It means that a foreign key can be set to null if it is not declared not null?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it means.

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I know in MySQL, this error is returned when there is an issue with foreign key constraints being formed.  Additionally - if this table was created, deleted, and re-created, there may be an existing reference that doesn't line up.