# How to add null value to a foreign key column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on a Windows Forms application using C#. I have two tables (`tblBatch` & `tblProduct`). These tables are related to each other based on the `BatchID`.

i.e

```
-> tblBatch
    BatchID
    BatchName
```

And

```
-> tblProduct
    ProductID
    ProductName
    BatchID
```

Now there are two different situations.

1. Product registration (adding a specific item to the database - stalk quantity could be empty because this will just register a product.
2. Supplying stalk quantity, updating the quantity amount of the products and assigning the `batchNo` to products.

At this point, the `batchID` must already be present in the database before I would assign it to a product in `tblProduct`. Because, product batch cannot be assigned before supply of products, and as during this stage, I don't have any supply which can give me an idea of the current `batchNo`. So during product registration, I just want to assign null to the `BatchID` in `tblProduct`. Once a supply will be performed later, I will update this ID and will assign the exact `BatchID` to the supplied Items.

However, I am getting the following error even I have tried keeping the `BatchID` field null in `tblProduct` but still I am unable to add record into the database.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tblProduct_tblBatch". The conflict occurred in database "myDB", table "dbo.tblBatch", column 'BatchID'.

Is there any solution to this problem? Or someone suggest me a simple way to resolve this specific problem.

Comment: Your logic is correct, you would want to assign `null` to `tblProduct:BatchId`. Why that is not working I (and anyone else reading this) don't know because there is no code in your question. If you want help please include the code where you do the assignment and persisting of the new record. Better yet, include an [mcve].

Comment: Check the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null