# When Configuring an entity for DbContext in .Net, how do I represent a collection of objects with a unidirectional relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I am doing an object configuration for entity framework where object A has contains a ICollection and object B does not have any relationship to this object. How would I configure this?

Here is an example of my object setup

```
public class A {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> itemsILike { get; set;}
}

public class B {
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

B doesn't need to know about A at all, but I want A to have a list of B that it can add or remove from (and can also be empty)

This is what I currently have, but I do not think this creates the correct relationship

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<A> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.id);

            builder.HasMany(e => e.itemsILike);
        }

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<B> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(e => e.id);
        }
```

Any Idea as to how to configure?

Comment: *B doesn't need to know about A at all, but I want A to have a list of B that it can add or remove from (and can also be empty)* its not how you do Entity Framework One-To-Many relationship. That being said, you can have navigation property on `B` to `A` set to have [`private`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private) access modifier. And ensure that that the [foreign key column allows null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2366979/4648586).

Comment: so be would contain an extra property?

Comment: kind of, contractually the `-Many` part of the relationship had to have navigation property into the `One-` part as far as i know. Otherwise, Entity Framework will simply thinks its not a sql relation at all.

Comment: So I could change B to 

public string id { get; set; }
public ICollection<A> as { get; set; }
?

Answer (score 0):

In order to store information about which `B`s belong to an `A` the database needs to store this information somewhere. Without it would not be able to establish which `B`s to return when you are retrieving a record of `A`.

This can be either via a foreign key `aId` on `B` or via a many-to-many relationship with an intermediate/join table that contains at least `aId` and `bId`.

---

There also is the option of storing a collection of `Bs` in a column of `A` and deserialising it in code. An example would be to store a comma-separated list of ids as a single string and add an access property/function which deseralise the data. For complex types you could use `json`.

Please note I'm not advocating storing json,, but if you cannot/don't_want to store the relationship as a column of `B` this could be a solution.

---

BTW. For EF Core you may want to look at [No Foreign Key Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#no-foreign-key-property) and Shadow Properties mentioned there.