# How to design tables with foreign key but value is NULL in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to design a database with 2 tables. `Project` and `Student`.

```
Student

| StudentID | ProjectID |
|-----------|-----------|
| 1         | NULL      |
| 2         | 1         |
```

```
Project

| ProjectID | Info      |
|-----------|-----------|
| 1         | some info |
| 2         | some info |
```

`Student` table records what project each student selects, and the student could only select a project that exists in the `project` table.

However, when a student first enrolls in the class, I want to insert his info into the `student` table but at that time, he did not pick any project yet so the `ProjectID` would be NULL.

This is not allowed when I make `Student - ProjectID` as a foreign key because `NULL` does not exist in `Project`.

What should I do?

Comment: Normally you would have a table of students, a table of projects, and a table relating one to the other

Comment: "This is not allowed" Why do you think that? Please read about how SQL FKs work. Please do reasonable research including the manual & goolging before considering asking a question. Please don't ask duplicate questions. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply declare a foreign key on a nullable column:

```
create table students (
    . . . 
    projectID int,   -- nullable by default
    constraint fk_students_project foreign key (projectID) references projects(projectID)
);
```

Of course, you need to create the `projects` table first, so the foreign key declaration is valid.

Answer (score 0):

MySQLs does allow a NULL value on a column that has a foreign key on it.

If you get an error message it is likely the column was declared NOT NULL or something like the NULL value was submitted as varchar

[Can table columns with a Foreign Key be NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null)