# Design of MySqlDb (v 8.0): What are the possible sacrifices I make when I decide not to put "Not null" constraint on a foreign key in the table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a question related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null) already answered question regards to MySql DB design. I was wondering what are the possible problems/sacrifices related to a decision not to put a "Not Null" constraint on foreign keys in the table? (As mentioned in the linked question, I can have multiple foreign keys in one table and I do not have to always know all of them when uploading data)

**Here is an example (simplified):**
There are three tables in my DB:

1. Company
2. Investor
3. Investment
   Investment table has among others following columns:

- Company FK
- Investor FK

**Problem:**
I wanted to know what will be the consequences for the end user, f.e. data analyst, when I will allow "Null value" for Investor FK.

Therefore I think, my question was best answered by **Vojta F** who showed me both pros and cons of my solution from a perspective of a DB user.

Comment: You "sacrifice" up to one byte storage space per row for the isNULL flag. But do you have a choice?

Comment: Put everything needed for your question in your post. Show what you have done towards answering a question. "possible problems/sacrifices" is not a valid SO question. Nevertheless this is a faq. (Which clearly we can expect.) Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a DB user (i.e. not a DB admin) I think it is perfectly fine to omit a `not null` constraint from a foreign key if you don't know its value upon upload. The effect of such an omission is two-fold:

- positive: it will be easier for you to upload new data - you won't be forced to insert a fkey value which I think is fine as long as you are aware of this when joining on this column ,
- negative: weaker data integrity: it will be harder to resolve records among multiple tables and you'll have to think about the `null`s when joining.

Answer (score 1):

In general the *gain* for using `NULL` *when you need it* exceeds any performance, etc, loss (or even gain).

The space consumed so small as to be not worth computing.

The speed considerations are usually non-existent.  The Optimizer does a *few* things differently depending on the `NULLability` of a indexed column.  But, again, your benefit of having (or not having) `NULL` is likely to exceed any downside.

There are a *small number* of restrictions.  A `PRIMARY KEY` must include `NOT NULL` column(s).